# Detecting system language in Julia

Tags: operating-system, julia

How can I detect the OS default language in Julia?  I expected there maybe to be a Sys variable, but there doesn’t seem to be one.  In python there is a locale package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 julia> ENV["LANG"]
 "en_US.UTF-8"
```

This should work on Linux, at least. I'm not sure about Windows.

Comment: I can confirm that it also works on Windows 10.